# Assigning tasks to workers of different skill level

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic, queue, task

Suppose we have a stream of nonidentical tasks that flow in and a set of nonidentical workers to handle them.

To simplify, let's say there are K types of tasks and N workers.

Each worker will take a different amount of time to handle each of the K types of tasks (we can represent the time it takes in a N x K matrix, which is assumed to be known).

Given the distribution of task inflow (say Poisson with some parameter and each task is equally likely to be one of the K tasks), what's an algorithm that will minimize the average wait time of the tasks?

Thanks

Comment: The underlying problem is the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). The fact that the full task list is not initially known means that you're trying to solve the problem with incomplete information. That is typically mitiagated by running a backlog, so that, for example, the next day's tasks are queued up while the current day's tasks are being completed.

Comment: I see. So no optimal algorithm exists, I assume. The best solution I was able to find was some sort of online learning procedure